# Is there a way to hide the desktop items using applescript WITHOUT quitting finder?

Tags: file, applescript, hide, desktop

Is there an applescript command that will make the desktop items disappear (without trashing them, moving them or quitting finder)?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I'm ] Not yet on Mavericks (how embarrassing), but this works on 10.6.8:

```
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop -bool false"
quit application "Finder"
delay 0.5
tell application "Finder" to activate
```

--and of course change false to true to re-activate the icon visibility

[edit] This solution works on Mavericks as well, and I assumed the request for a solution "without quitting finder" does not mean *temporarily* quitting the Finder, which is a necessary step.

Comment: haha but i use mavericks...theres no way to do it on mavericks yet?

Comment: I meant that **I** don't have Mavericks yet. It may work. Try it.